# Adding multiple images in MySQL DB with comma separated format using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am new to PHP Programming. I want to browse multiple images at once. During an on-click of submit button I want to save all selected image path in comma separated format in single row. I am getting confused to where i put insert query statement.

Currently I am using following code for this functionality

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
$hostname_connect= "localhost";
$database_connect= "test";
$username_connect= "root";
$password_connect= "";
$connect_solning = mysql_connect($hostname_connect, $username_connect, $password_connect) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
@mysql_select_db($database_connect) or die (mysql_error());

if(isset($_FILES['files']))
{
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name )
    {
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 2097152)
        {
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }

        $desired_dir="user_data";
        if(empty($errors)==true)
        {
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false)
            {
                // Create directory if it does not exist
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        
            }

            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false)
            {
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"user_data/".$file_name);
            }
            else
            {   
                 //rename the file if another one exist
                 $new_dir="user_data/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }
            //mysql_query($query);          
        }
        else
        {
                print_r($errors);
        }

        echo $file_name = $file_name.",";
        $query="INSERT into upload_data (FILE_NAME,FILE_SIZE,FILE_TYPE) VALUES('$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
        mysql_query($query);
    }


    if(empty($error))
    {
        echo "Success";
    }       
}
?>    

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

How do I save the images to the database in a comma separated format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct comma separated string from the submitted image paths and then insert that into the database. Insert should go after foreach loop.

Comment: but how i create comma separated string.i try this echo $file_name = $file_name.",";  is it correct?